# Identify Request return of (id)result

Tags: ios, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I am retrieving some user date out of my iOS app (me/friens, me/events, ...) I want to forward this JSON to a server where I do some additional data processing.

The thing is that I get an answer for my me/events object without any kind of identifier:

```
 (
    {
    data =         (
```

The only thing I get is this 'data' string: But how is it possible to manipulate the JSON in the way that I get an identifier like:

```
 (
    {
    events =         (
```

Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, you've got the request for which you are receiving a response in the - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response; method

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know what data is in the response. Is it events, friends, or personal information. It is only data = ( ... ) But if I get three responses with all the time data in it and append it to one NSMutableArray I can not parse this resulting JSON with 3 or more times data in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. Of couse this is not JSON. It is the output of a NSDictionary object. If you want to enable Facebook SSO in your Application and handle open graph data after the User logged in you just send the Facebook Id and the access_token to the server to perform additional tasks.